# JAXB Marshal does not convert the separator from a byte array

Tags: java, arrays, xml, jaxb, byte

I need to create xml file.
I have a PDF document that is converted into a byte array:

```
document.setContent(Base64.encode(fileData,true).getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
```

in method Base64.encode(fileData,true) - "true" parameter is set line separator every 76 characters.

then the following code:

```
File file = new File("C:\\123.xml");
FileOutputStream tmpStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
getMarshaller(contextPath).marshal(jaxbElement, tmpStream);
Writer out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(tmpStream));
out.flush();
out.close();
```

the final result in the file without separator:

```
<document>
 <content>SlZCRVJpMHhMak1OSmVMano5TU5DamcySURBZ2IySnFEUW84UENBdlRHbHVaV0Z5YVhwbFpDQXhJQTB2VENBek5qQTBOemNnRFM5SQ0KSUZzZ09ESTVJREl3TWlCZElBMHZUeUE0T1NBTkwwVWdNV</content>
</document>
```

I can not understand why. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Check "End-of-Line Handling" section [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-line-ends).
First of all, I suggest you to replace all CRLF with "&#10;" (unicode character for line feed) prior to writing XML file.